# Specific website crashes network

Tags: wireless-networking, safari, macos-sierra

I am experiencing strange issues with the website [3DTuning.com](http://3dtuning.com) on Safari in macOS.
Whenever I visit the site, it loads without issues however after a few minutes my WiFi network crashes and I need to reboot the router.

I have run Network Diagnostics and tested it over several weeks - this happens every time. Could somebody shed some light on this problem?

Comment: What is the make, model, hardware revision, and firmware version of your router? Also, is it updated to the latest firmware from the vendor? Maybe that website loads a lot of resources via separate HTTP requests, and your router has a bug where its NAT code can’t handle that many simultaneous connections.

Comment: I’ll see if I can find that information, I’ll get back to you soon.

Comment: The router is very new, if that helps.